# How do I Filter and extracting some values from columns

Tags: sql, google-sheets, filter, double, spreadsheet

Halo there, i need some helps. I want to make some database to figure out every product by category_name within their partner_id and status.

I want to breakdown the product_id by category_name (using split maybe) and those breakdown values (category_name) then pulls the data from column partner_id and status. in other words, i want to multiplies the product id by category_name and pulls values from status and partner_id.

I just knowing to filter all the breakdown values (category_name) with formulas FILTER and FLATTEN, but dont know how to generate data from column status and partner id..

Heres the data, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t7YSGoMrKPYlKaZkpEaxRnst-MsIpKp2RtVCm20iVcM/edit?usp=sharing

The tab 'output' is the expected result.

All helps so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Δ;map(B2:B;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;counta(split(Σ;",")))));
       {index(reduce({A1\C1:D1};sequence(counta(A2:A));lambda(a;c;{a;if(sequence(index(Δ;c));index({A2:A\C2:D};c))})))\
        {B1;tocol(map(B2:B;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;split(Σ;","))));1)}})
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for helping me, these formula such a comprehensive way, I need to learn each part of these formula.